# std::set and its front_insert_iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I know I can do this:

```
std::vector<double> vec;
std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<double> > it( back_inserter(vec) );
it = 4.5;
```

But I'd like to do something similar (in *syntax*) to `std::set` (and use a `front_insert_iterator` instead of a reference to the set and use `set::insert`). Is it possible, or am I forced to use a reference o the set? Maybe I should use `std::merge` and/or `std::set_intersect` (this would allow for good error reporting in case of duplicates)? Would this be a good approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't `push_back` or `push_front` to `set`, because (conceptually) a `set` is a sorted associative container.  You can do this, though:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef set<int> MySet;
    MySet si;
    insert_iterator<MySet> it(si, si.begin());

    *it = 1;
    *it = 2;

}
```

### EDIT:

Note that the `begin()` that the iterator is initialized with is *not* where the elements get put.  Rather, it is a hint to the STL where to start looking for where to put the item.

### EDIT2:

As per the comments below, you also wanted a way to check the "disposition" of the inserted item.  That is, a way to tell if the item was or was not already present before you inserted it.

You cannot do this directly using *only* the iterator.  If you need this information, you have two choices.

1) Don't use the insert iterator.  The only way to get the `bool` you get from `set::insert` is to call `set::insert`.  So call `set::insert`

42) Check the size of the `set` both before and after insertion.  If the size grew by one, the item was inserted. :)  I've market this as item #42 because IMO it is much less favorable than just calling `insert` directly for a number of reasons.  There may be multithreading issues, there may be a performance hit in computing `size()`, etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. How can I check the success of the insertion? Thanks!

Comment: @runenvb:  What do you mean, "success?"  The items will be inserted.  Are you wanting to check if there already was a matching element?

Comment: yes, the same information as provided by `std::set::insert().second`.

Comment: Thanks for the unfortunately unsatisfying answer :(... back to the designing board ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert to the "back" or "front" of a `set`. Perhaps what you're looking for is `std::inserter`.

http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/insert-iterator.html

Answer (score 1):

To use `front_insert_iterator` the container must have member `push_front` defined (such as standard containers `deque` and `list`).